# OSX: Record layer containing AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to .mov file

Tags: macos, avfoundation

I've spent some time organizing multiple video inputs that are nicely displayed in a layer that has multiple **AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer**s

E.g.

```
video1PreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(sessionWithNoConnection:avsession)
screenPreviewLayer?.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 100, 100)

video2PreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(sessionWithNoConnection:avession)
screenPreviewLayer?.frame = CGRectMake(100,0, 100, 100)
```

Is there an easy way that I can then write that to a .mov file using the above layout?